Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IconType'
I created these types
type IconType = {
    ico: "dashboard" | "program" | "score" | "record";
};

type NavigationRoute = {
    label: string;
    href: string;
    ico: IconType;
};

I receive "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IconType'" when I implement the NavigationRoute in this array:
const navigationRoutes: NavigationRoute[] = [
    {
        label: "Panel de control",
        href: "/panel",
        ico: "dashboard"
    },
    {
        label: "Items de puntuación",
        href: "/puntuacion",
        ico: "score"
    },
    {
        label: "Orden de salida",
        href: "/programa",
        ico: "program"
    }
];

The ico variable seems to be the issue here. Can anyone shed some light on this please?
I added string to the union definition yet it still doesn't work.
type IconType = { ico: string | "dashboard" | "program" | "score" | "record"; };
I created this playground with the code.

You’ve set your type to be an object with an ico property, so you’d need your nav objects to have a nested object {…, ico: {ico:”dashboard”}} with the current type definition

You should set your type to the union directly if that’s the value you’re after for the ico property

Would like to suggest to rename the ico property to icon, so it's self describing and consistent with its type (iconType).

You simply have extra curly braces in the IconType type definition.
This is what you are looking for:
type IconType = "dashboard" | "score" | "program";

It's one of those silly mistakes you need someone else to point out for you :)

This solves the problem. Thank you so much!
